# What's the regex to convert "SELECT whatever FROM" to "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM"?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I basically want to be able to take any non nested SQL string and convert it to the SQL to get the count all with the same regex.

It just has to be able to match anything between SELECT and FROM one time and replace with count(*) but I haven't allocated experience points to leveling up my regex yet.

i.e.

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM my_table where..."  to "SELECT count(*) FROM my_table where...
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where..."  to "SELECT count(*) FROM my_table where...
```

Comment: What programming language are you using. Replacing strings are dependent on the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from ( <insert original sql here> ) as X
```

Answer (score 0):

For a regex, you could use a simple one demonstrated [here](https://regex101.com/r/yLilz3/1).

Essentially we replace whatever is in between `SELECT` and `FROM` with `COUNT(*)`. Details are at the link as well.

Note that this will assist you in your thinking but is no way tested in depth. Please run some tests on  your own.

You could also use the link to generate code in Python, JavaScript etc.

Edit 1: the link was enclosed as a code snippet and so did not work. Removed the code meta tag.

Comment: *[here][1]* where?

Answer (score 0):

I always believe `regex` should be used when you have no simpler or any option at all. In your case, you can do this with simple SQL logic instead of regex. You can pass the original query as-is to your MySQL procedure or whatever and do this:

```
set @inputQuery = 'SELECT col1, col2 FROM my_table where id = 1'; -- you will pass this

set @startIndex = locate('select', @inputQuery) + char_length(rtrim('select'));
set @endIndex = locate('where', @inputQuery);
set @subString = substring(@inputQuery, @startIndex, @endIndex - @startIndex);
set @finalQuery = replace(@inputQuery, @subString, ' count(*) ');

select @finalQuery;
```

Output:

```
SELECT count(*) where id = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL, you can use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and then `FOUND_ROWS()` with any query.  So:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS . . .
FROM . . .
```

Then to get the number of rows:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

This is defined in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).